# Read the ID of a xbee with Arduino Fio and send it over Serial Communication

Tags: serial-port, xbee

I am trying to network multiple Arduino Fio with Xbee as slaves and my computer as Master with an Explore and Xbee.

Suppose i send and command 'Read' over serial to all Arduinos. Everyone responds suppose 'OK'.

My problem is to make them respond something like 'Arduino ID1 says OK' or 'Arduino ID2 says OK' etc.

Now this may be easy of each arduinos have separate programs burnt into them. But in my case all arduinos are suppose to have identical programs.

I know we assign MyID and Pan ID to each Xbee while configuring them for the first time.

So i am looking for some function in the program burnt into the Arduinos  example

'readMyXbeeID()' or something.

Any ideas how i can do this? Or any other way to achieveArd the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get MYID by using AT commands.
You will need to read the XBEE documentation confirm these.

Use `"+++"` to get in to command mode (not forgetting the > one second delay to 'guard' this sequence).

{ I used:  `delay(1200);  Serial.print ( "+++" ) ;` }

The `XBEE` will respond `OK\r`.
Then `ATMY\r` will give you `MYID returned as an ascii string terminated with "\r"`.
[In my case I had set a `MYID` of 2 so I saw the string `"2\r"`]

Finish with the command `ATCN\r` to exit command mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage communications with several devices, I recommend you to use the API mode instead of the AT mode. If you are working with Arduino, there are some really good libraries: [Xbee-Api](http://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/) and [XBee-Arduino](http://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/). Here you will find useful information and examples that may help in your project.

I mentored a few projects with these libraries (complete beginners in ZigBee technology), and they got all concepts really fast. 100% recomendable.

Regarding your question, you are right about writing just one program for all Arduinos. Otherwise you will have to create different hex-files for each node, which makes no sense. The easiest way for identifiying the ZigBee nodes is just using i.e. the 64-bit physical address. You can get this address easily through AT Commands. But keep in mind that in API Mode, whenever you send a message, the source address is automatically included in the frame, so you do not have to include explicity this information.